# How to fix docker-machine ip?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-toolbox

I am running a Docker container with docker-toolbox for windows and i am struggling to access it.

I can only access my container from the physical host and while using a LAN IP such as 192.168.x.x.

I want to fix this situation somehow, what are my options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is only seen when docker-toolbox is needed and on window versions that use hyper-v by default (such as Windows Server 2012 RC2 and similars).

The problem is that VirtualBox and Hyper-V cannot co-exist on the same machine.  Only one hypervisor can run at a time, and since Hyper-V runs all the time, while VirtualBox only runs when it is launched, VirtualBox is the loser in this scenario.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. disable hyper-v:

   - open cmd as admin and type: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
2. [configure virtual box to use hiper-v aswell](https://jayvilalta.com/blog/2016/04/28/installing-docker-toolbox-on-windows-with-hyper-v-installed//)